# Android manage constant class

Tags: java, android

I create constant class , include my url constant , my user web calls .... etc

I put my constant class in Utils package

here is my questions , is it good to inset constant class in Utils package ?

second question , should I separate each element create constant file for url , user ... etc

```
// url constants
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static String BASE_URL = "mybaseurl";

    public static final String LOGIN_URL           = "login.php";
    public static final String FORGETPASS_URL      = "restpassword.php";
    public static final String SINGUP_URL          = "signup.php";
    public static final String ALLDIEASES_URL      = "alldisease.php";
    public static final String QUESTIONS_URL       = "questions";
    public static final String EDITPROF_URL        = "editprofile";
    public static final String PROF_URL            = "profile";


    public static final String APPLICATION_JSON ="application/json";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE ="Content-Type";



    // login activity constants
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static final String IS_LOGGEDIN       = "isloggedin";
    public static final String TAG_username      = "user_name";
    public static final String TAG_useremail     = "user_mail";
    public static final String TAG_userpassword  = "user_password";
    public static final String TAG_REGID         = "regestration_id";
    public static final String REMEMBER_ME       = "remember";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final String TRUE          = "true";
    public static final String FALSE         = "false";
    public static final String RESULT        = "result";
    public static final String RESPONSE      = "response";
    public static final String TAG_USER      = "user";
    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS   = "success";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static final String TAG_postImageiD                   = "imagepath";
    public static final String TAG_postid                        = "post";
    public static final String TAG_age                           = "age";
    public static final String GeneralURL_TWO                    = "http://www.la3nyk.com/actions.php?Act=profilephoto&";
    public static final String SharedPreferenceDataStoreKey      = "keyprefs";
    public static final String TAG_user_photo                    = "user_photo";
    public static final String Tag_DesaesID                      = "disease";
    public static final String Tag_UPLOADURL                     = "http://la3nyk.com/servies/profilephoto.php/";
    public static boolean REFRESH                                = false;


    // user parser data

    public static final String USER_ID         = "user_id";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL      = "user_mail";
    public static final String USER_AGE        = "user_age";
    public static final String USER_NAME       = "user_name";
    public static final String USER_PASSWORD   = "user_password";
    public static final String USER_PHOTO      = "user_photo";
    public static final String USER_POSTS      = "posts";
    public static final String MESSAGE         = "message";
    public static final String DATA            = "data";


    // Diseases parser data
    public static final String DISEASE_ID          = "disease_id";
    public static final String DISEASE_NAME        = "disease_name";
    public static final String DISEASE_DES         = "description";
    public static final String DISEASE_REASONS     = "reasons";
    public static final String DISEASE_SYSMPTOMS   = "symptoms";
    public static final String DISEASE_DIAGNOSIS   = "diagnosis";
    public static final String DISEASE_TRATMENT    = "tratment";
    public static final String DISEASE_ADVICE      = "advice";
    public static final String DISEASE_VIDEO       = "disease_vedio";
    public static final String DISEASE_PHOTO       = "disease_photo";
    public static final String DISEASE_REF         = "refrancesrefrances";
    public static final String DISEASE_LINKS       = "links";

    // user parser data
    public static final String ALERT             = "alert";
    public static final String DONTSHOWAGAIN     = "dontshowagain";


    // question parser data
    public static final String QUESTION_ID     = "quest_id";
    public static final String QUESTION        = "quest";
    public static final String CHOOSE_1        = "chose1";
    public static final String CHOOSE_2        = "chose2";
    public static final String CHOOSE_3        = "chose3";
    public static final String CHOOSE_4        = "chose4";
    public static final String G_ID            = "G_id";


    // checks constants
    public static final String EYE_DISTANCE          = "eye_distance";
    public static final String COVER_EYE             = "cover_eye";
    public static final String ASTIGMATISM           = "astigmatism";
    public static final String RED                   = "red";
    public static final String CENTRAL_VISION        = "central_vision";
    public static final String VISION_ACUITY         = "vision_acuity";
    public static final String CONTRAST_SENSITIVITY  = "contrast_sensitivity";
    public static final String COLORBLIND            = "blind";


    // checks postions constants

    public static final int EYE_DISTANCE_INT         = 0;
    public static final int COVER_EYE_INT            = 1;
    public static final int ASTIGMATISM_INT          = 2;
    public static final int RED_INT                  = 3;
    public static final int CENTRAL_INT              = 4;
    public static final int VISION_ACUITY_INT        = 5;
    public static final int CONTRAST_SENSITIVITY_INT = 6;
    public static final int COLOR_BLIND_INT          = 7;


    // questions

    public static final String QUESTION_ONE          = "q1";
    public static final String QUESTION_TWO          = "q2";
    public static final String QUESTION_THREE        = "q3";
    public static final String QUESTION_FOUR         = "q4";
    public static final String QUESTION_FIVE         = "q5";
    public static final String QUESTION_SIX          = "q6";
    public static final String QUESTION_SEVEN        = "q7";
    public static final String QUESTION_EIGHT        = "q8";
    public static final String QUESTION_NINE         = "q9";
    public static final String QUESTION_TEN          = "q10";
    public static final String QUESTION_ELEVEN       = "q11";
    public static final String QUESTION_TWELVE       = "q12";
    public static final String QUESTION_THIRTEEN     = "q13";


    public static final String QUESTION_SIZE            = "question_size";
    public static final String CURRENT_QUESTION_TAG     = "current_question";
    public static final String CURRENT_QUESTION_POS     = "current_question_pos";
    public static final String CURRENT_QUESTION_SCORE   = "test_res_score";

    public static final String PASSED_BOOL_STATE        = "passed_result_state";
    public static final String PASSED_MSG_STATE         = "passed_message_state";
    public static final String PASSED_SCORE             = "passed_score";

    public static final String PASSED_DISEASES          = "mard";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up a significant number of concerns in this class. I will try to go over them one by one, but since you provided no context in your question there will be some guesswork involved...

---

The first section of this concatenation of constants is dedicated to some URLs.

> ```
> public static String BASE_URL = "mybaseurl";
>
> public static final String LOGIN_URL           = "login.php";
> public static final String FORGETPASS_URL      = "restpassword.php";
> public static final String SINGUP_URL          = "signup.php";
> public static final String ALLDIEASES_URL      = "alldisease.php";
> public static final String QUESTIONS_URL       = "questions";
> public static final String EDITPROF_URL        = "editprofile";
> public static final String PROF_URL            = "profile";
> ```

These should go into your specific Views on your app, so that the app knows what URL to request. the only thing that *may* belong into a central class is the `BASE_URL`, and that should be final and probably also a URL and not a String.

---

The next section is dedicated to HTTP communication:

> ```
> public static final String APPLICATION_JSON ="application/json";
> public static final String CONTENT_TYPE ="Content-Type";
> ```

This is not something your whole application needs to know about. This belongs into a class responsible for information transport. Something like a `RemoteDataFetcher` or similar. Because I have no overview of what your project structure is, I don't know whether such a class already exists or not.

If it doesn't exist, it seems time to make it exist. Encapsulate the details of information transport!

---

The next section is titled `login activity constants`... Question: Why are the constants for the `LoginActivity` **not in the LoginActivity?** These are (similarly to the `LOGIN_URL`) internals necessary for **this one class.** There is no point in making them generally available. If you "need them" somewhere else, your design is probably quite screwed and you should revisit it.

Then there is a section about... Tags. I have no idea how or where you use them, but they're probably better off in a class dedicated to these Tags.

Then there's `user parser data`... the same as for `login activity constants` applies... There is no need to broadcast into the whole application what a `UserParser` needs. That's an implementation detail, that your application doesn't need. Put these into `private static final` fields in the class dedicated to parsing users.

Same applies for `Diseases parser data` and `question parser data`.

---

In general **all of these constants** don't have to be available to the whole application. They're just local to specific parts of your application and should be kept (and maintained) there.

Putting them into a central class makes it unnecessarily hard on you to keep an overview (did you see there's two "user parser data" secions?) and unnecessarily complicate finding of names for new constants.

Overall this whole class seems a result of design mistakes in other places of your application.

Comment: why I am using constant class , to decrease other classes size , plus sometime I use constant across whole app